# master won't accept develops commits

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket, rebase

In our git Repo, we follow a fairly streight forward branching concept.
We have a master branch, a develop branch and feature branches.
Each feature is developed on it's own branch.
When done, it is merged into our develop branch for integration tests.
When that is done, the develop branch is being merged into the master branch.

However as of lately, our develop branch seems to be constantly 40 Commits ahead of our master branch, even after we merged the develop into the master branch.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue?
Otherwise each Merge consists of 40 commits, which we obviously don't want.

[image: Proof]

Comment: Can you run this commands and insert result in your question? 
```git fetch --all; git log --graph --decorate --all```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a `git pull remote branch` from your master branch.If your develop branch is still 40 commits ahead of your master branch, execute `git fetch`.

`git fetch` seems to update the local representation of the remote branch, which doesn't necessarily happen when you do a git pull remote branch.